# Permanently change canvas Postion in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a Monopoly  Game using WPF C# on Visual Studio.
I Have a problem I have made a dice Class that gives me random values for 2 Dices.

***Dice.Cs***

```
    namespace WpfApp1
 {
    /// <summary>
    /// class that throws two dices in the game
    /// </summary>
  public class Dice
     {
    public int FirstDice { get; set; }
    public int SecondDice { get; set; }
    public bool HasBeenThrown { get; set; }
    public Random Random { get; set; }


    public Dice()
    {
        HasBeenThrown = false;
        Random = new Random();
    }

    public int ThrowDice(Image m1,Image m2)
    {
        FirstDice = Random.Next(1, 6);
        SecondDice = Random.Next(1, 6);
        string s1 = FirstDice.ToString() + ".png";
        string s2 = SecondDice.ToString() + ".png";
        BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
        BitmapImage bi2 = new BitmapImage();
        bi2.BeginInit();
        bi2.UriSource = new Uri(s2, UriKind.Relative);
        bi2.EndInit();
        //---------------------------------------------
        bi3.BeginInit();
        bi3.UriSource = new Uri(s1, UriKind.Relative);
        bi3.EndInit();
        //--------------------------------------------
        m1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        m1.Source = bi3;
        m2.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        m2.Source = bi2;

        return (FirstDice + SecondDice);
    }

    public bool IsDouble()
    {
        return (FirstDice == SecondDice);
    }
}
}
```

And a Static Class Board to Store the Positions of each cell on the Board, also to get the current position of the players piece

***Board.cs***

```
namespace WpfApp1
 {

public class Pair<T, U>
{
    public Pair()
    {
    }

    public Pair(T first, U second)
    {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
    }

    public T First { get; set; }
    public U Second { get; set; }
};
public static class Board
{
    public static Tuple<int, int>[] Postions =
        {
         Tuple.Create(533,590),
         Tuple.Create(533,540),
         Tuple.Create(533,478),
         Tuple.Create(533,423),
         Tuple.Create(533,368),
         Tuple.Create(533,313),
         Tuple.Create(533,258),
         Tuple.Create(533,203),
         Tuple.Create(533,148),
         Tuple.Create(533,93),
         Tuple.Create(533,40),
         Tuple.Create(430,40),
         Tuple.Create(380,40),
         Tuple.Create(330,40),
         Tuple.Create(280,40),
         Tuple.Create(227,40),
         Tuple.Create(180,40),
         Tuple.Create(127,40),
         Tuple.Create(80,40),
         Tuple.Create(40,40),
         Tuple.Create(40,88),
         Tuple.Create(40,148),
         Tuple.Create(40,203),
         Tuple.Create(40,258),
         Tuple.Create(40,313),
         Tuple.Create(40,373),
         Tuple.Create(40,428),
         Tuple.Create(40,478),
         Tuple.Create(40,530),
         Tuple.Create(40,590),
         Tuple.Create(80,590),
         Tuple.Create(130,590),
         Tuple.Create(180,590),
         Tuple.Create(230,590),
         Tuple.Create(283,590),
         Tuple.Create(333,590),
         Tuple.Create(383,590),
         Tuple.Create(433,590),
         Tuple.Create(483,590)

        };


    public static int FindPos(double top, double left, ref Canvas c)
    {

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            if (Canvas.GetTop(c) == top && Canvas.GetLeft(c) == left)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
}
```

and this is the function responsible for moving the player's current Position

```
public static void Move(int num,ref Canvas c)
    {
        double left = Canvas.GetLeft(c);
        double top = Canvas.GetTop(c);
        int current=Board.FindPos(top, left,ref c);

        Canvas.SetLeft(c,Board.Postions[current+num].Item2);
        Canvas.SetTop(c,Board.Postions[current+num].Item1);
    }
```

The problem is that the canvas always moves from the start position and doesn't 
continue on moving on the board

images are linked for further explanation.

[The green piece is in the starting postion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7z7T.jpg)

[After one click it moved 5 positions as it should have done.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMJu.jpg)

[as you can see it started counting the moves from the Go cell but I want it to continue from where it stopped and I can't do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcDF7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a Piece class.  This would contain the current index of where it is located.
It starts at say 0.
You roll 5.

```
Piece.Position += roll;
```

It then knows it's in position indexed by 5.
Bind that via a converter or look it up and the piece goes to the location defined in Positions[5].
Next time you roll, you add the result to 5. Say that's 7.  It's index becomes 12.  That is then used to index the entry for it's location.

Don't use a piece of UI to retain the state, use a class.

Comment: [the class as implemented it](https://imgur.com/rS5bz4e)
it doesn't add the index value.  
@Andy